# VS Code intelephense shows incorrect error: Undefined method 'save'

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I'm using the intelephense v1.8.2 extension in VS Code and I'm working on a laravel project. As I get the user using `Auth::user();` and call `$user->save();` the intelephonse keep showing incorrect error `Undefined method 'save'`.
Is there a way to fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: Intelephense is correctly detecting that the User model class does not define a save method - that method exists on the Model base class.
Intelephense doesn't currently handle this sort of inheritance correctly, so you'll get spurious errors in this scenario.
There is an open issue to add support for PHP inheritance to Intelephense. In the meantime, you can suppress the error with a // @php-intel-disable-next-line comment, or by disabling linting for the file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `@var` to ignore this:

```
/** @var \App\Models\User $user **/
$user = Auth::user();
$user->name = 'alice';
$user->save();
```