# Many-to-Many relations Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to create a many to many relation between `user` and `courses`. I have created the migrations: new pivot table, foreign keys, and everything added the functions `belongstomany` to the models, but while doing the controller, it says `undefined method`.

This is my code (*formation* means *course*):

```
public function addFormationToUser(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $formationId = $request->input('formation_id');
    $user->formations()->attach($formationId);
}
```

the user model have this function

```
public function formations(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Formation::class, 'formation_user', 'formation_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: which method is undefined?

Comment: @mrhn the 'formations' method in this line $user->formations()->attach($formationId);

Comment: Share the full error please

Comment: Undefined method 'formations'.intelephense(1013)
function User::formations(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany

Comment: your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74338713/vs-code-intelephense-shows-incorrect-error-undefined-method-save

Comment: Could you provide both models definitions, and also database structure. We cannot reproduce anything